# Java: Returning an object from ScriptEngine javascript

Tags: javascript, java, eval

I'm trying to evaluate javascript in Java by using the [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) class. Here is a short example of what I am trying to do:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js"); //Creates a ScriptEngine
        Object obj = engine.eval("var obj = { value: 1 }; return obj; "); // Evals the creation of a simple object
        System.out.println(obj.value); // I get an invalid token error when trying to print a property of the object
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this *should* work... but I'm stumped, and I'll take any help I can get.

Comment: Does it work if you drop `return obj;`? Return statements should be in functions, but then I don't know how that class evaluates the JS code.

Comment: I'm not really sure how it works either; I just saw a couple of examples and the documentation. I get the same error when ommiting.

Comment: Probably because of the `var` statement, which won't return the object itself. Just the object wrapped in parentheses may work. The parens will be necessary for a valid program.

Comment: @squint OP has a compile error, (the "invalid token error" mentioned in the comment to the `println()` statement), not a runtime error. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38034571/5221149) for why.

Comment: @Andreas: I know, see my first comment. I'm just saying that neither `var obj = { value: 1 };` nor `{ value: 1 };` would likely work because neither statement alone produces an object, while `({value: 1})` would.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Note: The following is for Java 8, using the [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/) engine.*

First, to make the code compile, remove the `.value` from the `println()` statement. `obj` is declared to be type `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have a `value` field.

Once you do that, you get the following exception when running the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:25 Invalid return statement
var obj = { value: 1 };  return obj; 
                         ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 25
```

That is because you don't have a function, so you cannot call `return`. The return value of the script is the value of the last expression, so just say `obj`.

Now it will run and print `[object Object]`. To see what type of object you got back, change to `println(obj.getClass().getName())`. That will print [`jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html). I've linked to the javadoc for your convenience.

`ScriptObjectMirror` implements [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Bindings.html?is-external=true) which in turn implements `Map<String, Object>`, so you can call `get("value")`.

Working code is:

```java
import javax.script.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        Bindings obj = (Bindings)engine.eval("var obj = { value: 1 };  obj; ");
        Integer value = (Integer)obj.get("value");
        System.out.println(value); // prints: 1
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

> The whole point was to create an object with functions, is that possible with this engine? There isn't a Function object.

Example for how to do that:

```java
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String script = "var f = {\n" +
                        "  value: 0,\n" +
                        "  add: function(n) {\n" +
                        "    this.value += n;\n" +
                        "    return this.value;\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "};\n" +
                        "f; // return object to Java\n";
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        ScriptObjectMirror obj = (ScriptObjectMirror)engine.eval(script);
        System.out.println("obj.value = " + obj.getMember("value"));
        System.out.println("obj.add(5): " + obj.callMember("add", 5));
        System.out.println("obj.add(-3): " + obj.callMember("add", -3));
        System.out.println("obj.value = " + obj.getMember("value"));
    }
}
```

*OUTPUT*

```
obj.value = 0
obj.add(5): 5.0
obj.add(-3): 2.0
obj.value = 2.0
```

Comment: `/tmp/java_4eJZg9/Test.java:16: error: unreported exception ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Bindings obj = (Bindings)engine.eval("var obj = { value: 1 };  obj; ");
                                    ^
1 error` at the parentheses after eval.

Comment: So add `throws ScriptException` to `main()`.

Comment: Man, I am so dumb. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know this question is answered, but I can't seem to use the same code for Strings. Also, is it possible to set value to a function in javascript and then execute that function in Java? That was the entire purpose for this, it was to create dynamic functions.

Comment: Yes, just do what I described doing. Print the class name of the returned object, so you can see what you get. Then check the javadoc of how to use it.

Comment: The whole point was to create an object with functions, is that possible with this engine? There isn't a Function object.

Comment: @Adam How would you do that, given that `Bindings` doesn't have the necessary `getMember(...)` and `callMember(...)` methods? And note that `ScriptObjectMirror implements Bindings`.

Comment: Apologies, I was mistaking ScriptObjectMirror as an internal JDK class as Eclipse was hiding it. Obviously it is not. In a much simpler use case I used get() instead of getMember() for accessing variables.